# An email sent using Python "smtplib" module arrives empty

Tags: flask, smtplib

**Problem:** When I send an email it does get sent from email1@hotmail.com to email2@hotmail.com but the email is empty. However, when I send the email using Gmail the email arrives with the content.

```
@app.route('/')
        def email():
            msg= 'Hello'
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login("email1@hotmail.com", "Password1")
            server.sendmail("email1@hotmail.com", "email2@hotmail.com", msg)
            return 'Message Sent!'
```

**Desirable result:** I want to see the content when I open the email in email2@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it, but it might be necessary to add

```
"From: email1@hotmail.com\r\nTo: email2@hotmail.com\r\n\r\n"
```

in the beginning of `msg`.

So I would try with

```
msg = 'From: email1@hotmail.com\r\nTo: email2@hotmail.com\r\n\r\nHello'
```

and see if that works better.

Gmail might be more forgiving over such things than Hotmail.

Note also the blank line (`\r\n\r\n`) before the "Hello".

Comment: This works, thanks! However, the email ends up in the junk folder. There was the same problem when I was using Gmail without subject. Hotmail seem to be more strict. Any idea how to prevent an email ending up in the junk folder?

Comment: Glad it worked! About the junk folder, the more it looks like spam, the more likely it is to end up in the junk or spam folder. So if you put some more text that makes it look more "real", it's likely it won't end up there. It's hard to say exactly what's needed, but adding subject, meaningful text, etc., will probably help. It could help setting up rules about specific recipients, and/or adding the sender address (email1@hotmail.com in this case) to your Contacts.

Comment: Indeed hotmail can be configured for a specific email address. 
It can be done directly from the junk folder by clicking on "It's not junk" above the message.